# is this a bug in notepad? hex 31 0A

Tags: notepad, hex-editors

I was testing a program then I discovered if I have 55 or 63 1 and line feed

```
hex (31) and hex (0A)
```

notepad fails to open the file? it shows gibberish (see screenshot)

[image]

This is what the hex editor look like:
[image]

But if I open the file in notepad++ , it opens ok.
attached is the text file in question.
http://wikisend.com/download/485846/tt.txt

I made a mistake: I figured out the patern. if I have 49 of "1". notepad can open the file OK (this is on windows 10 64 bit). Anything above 49, notepad cannot open it.

screenshot, this is tt49.txt working OK
[image]

[image]

this is the sample file that notepad can open
http://wikisend.com/download/456646/tt49.txt

Answer (score 1):

This is due to Notepad's limitation of how to understand line breaks.

It expects them to be encoded as HEX`0d0a` (`CARRIAGE RETURN LINE FEED`, `CR LF`, `\r\n`), otherwise it will fail to understand the encoding. Notepad++, Sublime Text, and basically every other modern Editor nowadays have no problems understanding different kinds of line breaks.

Look, e.g., [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations) for additional info.

Comment: Any idea why is it happen only when I have certain number of characters? if I have 54 it opens fine? but if I add to 55 then it fails to open?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior. Notepad does not show any correct characters in my case, regardless how many `310a` sequences my file has.

Comment: Thanks for testing it. but I actually find the pattern. 49 is the key number. anything above 49 notepad breaks. I am on 64bit windows 10 OS I don't know if that matters. can you open this file and see if notepad load it correctly? http://wikisend.com/download/456646/tt49.txt

Comment: On Windows 10 64, it displays the 1s, but without line breaks. On my older Windows XP Notepad, I just get the gibberish.

Comment: yea I think notepad does not understand 0A line feed. Notepad only understand CR LF which is 0D 0A..  thanks for opening and testing the file